# TS7053: No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'BaseReducer<T>'

Tags: javascript, typescript, web

I am getting the following error "TS7053: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'BaseReducer'.   No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'BaseReducer'."

This is the original code:

```
import IAction from '../models/IAction';

type ReducerMethod<T> = (state: T, action: IAction<any>) => T;

export default abstract class BaseReducer<T> {
  public initialState: T = {} as any;

  public reducer = (state: T = this.initialState, action: IAction<any>): T => {
    // if the action type is used for a method name then this be a reference to
    // that class method.
    // if the action type is not found then the "method" const will be undefined.
    const method: ReducerMethod<T> | undefined = this[action.type];

    // if the action type "method" const is undefined or the action is an error
    // return the state.
    if (!method || action.error) {
      return state;
    }

    // Calls the method with the correct "this" and returns the modified state.
    return method.call(this, state, action);
  };
}
```

I tried updating it to the following but I am still getting the same error, does anyone know how to fix this and why my fix doesn't seem to work? Thanks

```
import IAction from '../models/IAction';

type ReducerMethod<T> = (state: T, action: IAction<any>) => T;

interface IndexSignature {
  [key: string]: any
}

export default abstract class BaseReducer<T extends IndexSignature> {
  public initialState: T = {} as any;

  public reducer = (state: T = this.initialState, action: IAction<any>): T => {
    // if the action type is used for a method name then this be a reference to
    // that class method.
    // if the action type is not found then the "method" const will be undefined.
    const method: ReducerMethod<T> | undefined = this[action.type];

    // if the action type "method" const is undefined or the action is an error
    // return the state.
    if (!method || action.error) {
      return state;
    }

    // Calls the method with the correct "this" and returns the modified state.
    return method.call(this, state, action);
  };
}
```

Comment: Well it's BaseReducer which is lacking the index signature, not T, adding `[key: string]: any` to the class body should do the trick, but it's not pretty :P

Comment: Please consider editing the code above to constitute a [mcve] suitable for dropping into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play) to demonstrate your issue.  Presumably the `IAction` type is important here, but you haven't given its definition.  Good luck!